# How to split string, remove last element and join back in Java?

Tags: java

I have a array variable `filesFound` that holds a filename.  How do I go about removing the last number part including its extension.

```
...
File[] filesFound = SomeUtils.findFile("xyz","c:\\") 

//fileFound[0] is now "abc_xyz_pqr_27062016.csv"
//What I need is "abc_xyz_pqr" only

String[] t = filesFound[0].toString().split("_")
Arrays.copyOf(t, t.length - 1) //this is not working
...
```

Comment: What means not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Arrays.copyOf` returns a new array, so you have to assign it to t or a new variable:

```
t = Arrays.copyOf(t, t.length - 1)
```

Answer (score 10):

How about `.substring()` & `.lastIndexOf()`?

```
String file = filesFound[0];
String newFileName = file.substring(0, file.lastIndexOf("_"));
```

the `newFileName` would then contain everything up to (but not including) the last '_' char.

Comment: The "-1" is wrong. it should be substring(0,file.lastIndexof('_' ));

Comment: @FredK - You're right, in that `substring()` goes up to <em>but not including</em> the  2nd index value, so the -1 is not needed. **But** I still like the brevity of this over some of the other answers provided so far, and removing the -1 makes the code even less =)  so I removed it. Good catch by the way!

Answer (score 6):

Copying the array will not concatenate the parts back together. Try

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < t.length - 1; i++) {
    builder.append(t[i]);
}
String joined = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
System.out.println("abc_xyz_pqr_27062016.csv");       

System.out.println("abc_xyz_pqr_27062016.csv".replaceAll("_\\d+.+",""));
```

Prints out:

```
abc_xyz_pqr_27062016.csv
abc_xyz_pqr
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JAVA 8 or above, you can use [.limit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) and [Collector.joining()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--)

```
    String someString = "abc_xyz_pqr_27062016.csv";
    String[] splitArray = searchTerm.split("_");
    
    //Limiting the array length, not to consider last element while joining
    String stringAfterJoining = Arrays.stream(splitArray)
            .limit(splitArray.length - 1)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("_"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In a bit stress way..

```
            //fileFound[0] is now "abc_xyz_pqr_27062016.csv"

            String file = fileFound[0] ;
            String filter = "";
            int i = 0;
            char [] allChars = file.toCharArray();
            char oneChar ;
            while(i < (file.length()-4)){//4 is .csv
                oneChar = allChars[i];
                if((oneChar >= 65 && oneChar <=90)||(oneChar >= 97 && oneChar <=122)|| oneChar==95){
                    filter += oneChar;
                }
                i++;

            }
            filter = filter.substring(0, filter.length()-1);
            System.out.println(filter);
```

This works very fine